# How to use SOLID principles in this example

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, php, web-applications, solid

I have reading about SOLID principles last week and decided to try to solve real world problem by using them. So I got the problem of real world ecommerce site managing totals.

**Problem Statement:**
  We have to calculate some totals like subtotal, taxes, vouchers, coupon, total on a cart products.

So I have decided to make TotalManager which returns total_data and total to the rest of the program.

```
// total data variable looks like
array('key'=>value)
```

e.g. `array('subtotal'=>100,'total'=>150,'tax'=>50)`

```
    class TotalManager{
        private $total_data;
        public function get_total_data()
        {
            $totals = array('subtotal','total','taxes')         
            // foreach totals array gets each object check its instance of interface itotal and called it's get method.
        }        
    }

    Interface Itotal
    {
        public function get_total_data();
        public function get_total();
    }    

    class subtotal implements Itotal
    {
        public function get_total_data()
        {
            // it needs cart object
            // get the cart product calculate totals and return total_data and total 
        }
        public function get_total()
        {
            return the subtotal in double/float
        }
    }

    class total implements Itotal
    {
        public function get_total_data()
        {
            // get the other totals object  and calls it get_total method
            // calulate sum of all totals and return 
        }

        public function get_total()
        {
            // calculate total and return back;
        }
    }
```

But I am facing problems in this model:

For dependency inversion principle I cannot directly create the object of cart or subtotal in subtotal, Total class respectively I have to pass them from controller at total manager.

When I think about that whenever I am adding the class I have to change the Total manager for adding the new method so it's violating open/closed principle. How to solve this in OOD?

Comment: As a side note "Clean Code", the book that advocates the SOLID principles, also frowns upon using the word "manager" in your class names.

Answer (score 1):

I see you use php, try to stick to the psr coding styles: [psr-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [psr-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/).

---

Look into the decorator pattern. this is a pattern commonly used in this kind of situations.

---

You probably have some kind of `LineItem` class that is used to represent items in your cart. They probably look something like this:

```
interface LineItem
{
    public function getPrice();
}
```

With then an implementation for your product:

```
class ProductLineItem implements LineItem
{
    public function __construct(Product $product, $quantity) {
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->quantity = $quantity;
    }

    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->quantity * $this->product->getPrice();
    }
}
```

Now it is time to create our abstract decorator:

```
abstract class LineItemDecorator implements LineItem
{
    public function __construct(LineItem $item) {
        $this->item = $item;
    }

    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->item->getPrice(); //delegation
    }
}
```

> this abstract class is not needed. I just tend to use it to delegate everything to the base object only in one place. Especially useful if multiple methods exist.
>
> Note also how my Decorator implements the same interface!

And then now it's time for our Discounts:

```
class DiscountLineITemDecorator extends LineItemDecorator 
{
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->item->getPrice() * 0.75;
    }
}
```

We would then procede to use it:

```
$lineItem = new ProductLineItem($theProduct, 2);
$lineItemWithDiscount= new DiscountLineITemDecorator($lineItem);
//lets add it to our cart
$cart->addLineItem($lineItemWithDiscount);
```

Our cart then probably also has a `getPrice()` method. Probably it will look something like this:

```
foreach ($this->lineITems as $lineItem) {
    $price += $lineItem->getPrice();
}
return $price;
```

So what about discount on an entire cart?

```
$cartWithDiscount = new DiscountCartDecorator($cart);
```

and boom

```
$cartWithDiscount->getPrice();
```

> All code used here serves as an example. The naming can be improved a lot, so feel free to edit!

Comment: I am just thinking in the same way as decorator pattern works but i doesn't know it's called as a decorator pattern ie. passing the main totalmanager object to every subtotal class to achieve all totals.

Comment: but is it good to pass whole object to everyone who doesn't need it? I mean to say sub-total class needs cart but total class doesn't need it.

Comment: Added some examples

Comment: where are you defining class 'PriceDecorator'  which is extended by 'DiscountLineITemDecorator'

Comment: Not, I called it PriceDecorator, but I changed it to LineItemDecorator when copy-pasting to the answer. Edited the answer

Answer (score -2):

The Open/Closed principle allows you to add new methods.  You won't be able to alter the interface to existing methods.

It may be simpler to have a class that takes a cart and returns/recalculates the totals.  Try to avoid using this class to maintain state between calls.

Comment: will you please explain me about  'Try to avoid using this class to maintain state between calls'  And please help how was the design should I change it or not.

Comment: Are you going to say that I should only keep totalManager class and getTotal,getSubtotal will be method of that.

Comment: and sir it's also going to break the SRP in solid because class now can change when the any of total methods change it's behaviour

Comment: @siddhesh It would maintain SRP.   It would be a container for all totals, and would break SRP if you moved a total elsewhere.  Classes are expected to change as requirements change.   It would be possible to inject a list of sub-totalling classes.

Comment: sir will you please explain bit more? I m unable to get your point. @BillThor

Comment: will you show me the structure about what you r talking. please.

Comment: @siddhesh The single responsibility principle is more about thoroughly decomposing your domain into manageable features that are only eligible to change if the requirements of the area of the domain that they are directly responsible for also change.  The SRP is totally about the process of adequately *identifying* the single purpose of a system artifact than breaking your solution down into tons and tons and tons(I've seen this done. It is horrible to work with) of little classes that literally only do one thing (i.e. have one method)

Comment: @K.AlanBates yes sir, definately it's not good idea to have one method per class. but sir would you give me some guidence on how to find the reasons to club the methods? Let's say if i am making user management then db releted functionality should be go into the seperate class and other business logic like user registration will go into the seperate class? is this good idea?

Comment: @siddhesh Well...-at a basic level- yes. It is definitely a good idea to separate "business logic" from "db related functionality" into separate artifacts. But that is not quite where I was trying to go with my initial comment. In any non-trivial system, these two responsibilities are far too abstract to consider them a "single responsibility"

Comment: @siddhesh if we're only considering "registration" for the sake of argument (and assuming it is a feature of a larger 'user management' system) then your design may include an artifact to receive a request, an artifact to validate input, an artifact to submit valid input to the backend system, an artifact to serve as proxy for your persistence store, and an artifact that is an encapsulating façade over your "User Management" system. To do less likely does not go far enough. To do more without specific reason to do so is likely over engineering.

Comment: @siddhesh Do not treat the "SOLID" principles as some dogma for 'good' software.  Specifically, the 'S' and the 'D' can cause the complexity of your solution to absolutey *explode* if taken to their ultimate end (everything does one and only one thing | every dependency injected whether it needs to be or not)  The point of the SOLID principles is to *improve* the quality and *reduce* the pain of building software.  Where quality is reduced and pain increased,SOLID is being used wrong.

Comment: @siddhesh There are 4 very basic principles from the epoch of the agile development movement that were part of XP. The point of all of these "principles" is to produce the most robust software possible with the simplest design necessary; to accomplish that goal is to produce elegant software. Simple software [ {1:Passes all its tests},{2:Contains no duplication},{3:Clearly expresses the developer's intent},{4,Uses the least number of classes, lines of code, and methods to accomplish these goals}] Combine those 4 with "SOLID" and 'you will be a man, my son' (to quote Kipling)

Comment: Thanks @K.AlanBates I will try to maintain my code quality. It will take time. but I will learn it Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Sorry for the one more question but will you please explain me about word 'artifact'

Comment: @siddhesh Oh! "Artifact" is used as an abstract term to mean "anything tangible produced during the development process" but for purposes of this discussion, you can replace the word "artifact" with "class" in my comments and they mean the same thing.