# Implementing "buy one get one for free" coupon logic for shopping cart

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, php, e-commerce

Trying to solve **bogo coupon** logic with proper design pattern, but having trouble identifying one.
Use case: "Buy *iPad* get *SmartCase* for free"

Suppose we have the following objects:

```
Product:
 - getPrice

CartItem(Product p, quantity):
 - getPrice

Cart:
 - getItems()
 - addItem(CartItem ci)

Coupon(code):
 - getCode

CouponBuyOneGetOneFree(code) extends Coupon: (not sure about inheritance here)
```

1) What design pattern fits here?
2) What if i needed to set up the same logic without coupon but in product settings itself?

I have implemented `Decorator pattern` for `CartItem` when discount is applied to the **same** `CartItem` by [this example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/289482/how-to-use-solid-principles-in-this-example) and it works great, but still can not achieve the result of this use case.

Somehow I need to check that *Ipad* and *SmartCase* both are in the cart and apply discount to *SmartCase* only. Also if I add another *iPad* i should get another *SmartCase* for free.

Comment: The price of each item depends on the cart as a whole. I would add a PricingService(Cart cart) which sets the price of each item according to your discount logic

Comment: that is something i am trying to do. just can not decide should this service return discount price or update the CartItem->discount value. i thought maybe i am missing some kind of pattern here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No design pattern is required beside basic subclassing. You just need a *Coupon* interface with a single method: *calculateDiscount(cart, customer)*. Create an implementation of *Coupon* for each different kind of discount, e.g. a *FreeAddonCoupon* or a *LoyaltyCoupon*.

So a Cart has CartItems and Coupons. Add the price of the items, subtract the discount for each coupon.

Comment: so i basicly just add discount=0 property to CartItem and update its value with calculateDiscount method, right?

Comment: @Putna: No. The total price of the cart should be calculated by adding the prices of the items and then subtracting the discounts of the coupons. There is no reason for a `CartItem` to know about the possibility of a discount.

Comment: i want to display the amount of discount for each item in the cart, something like striketrough price.

Answer (score 2):

Real world process seems suitable here. I would separate collection of `Coupons` from `Cart` (`CartItems` collection) by encapsulating them in `Checkout` object.

Items in cart have its standard price until coupons changes it. Discounts are given at checkout and so does free items. Checkout process goes like this:

1. Each `CartItem` is taken out from cart and becomes `CheckoutItem`
2. `CheckoutItem` has additional property - discount (0 at start)
3. Each `Coupon` takes a peak at `CheckoutItem` collection and based on what's in there:

   - increases discount of single item,
   - adds "free" item
   - adds "meta-item" with negative price (total/subtotal discounts)
4. Additional items are ignored by subsequent coupons (`price > 0` should suffice) to avoid cascade effect
5. Coupons that changed something at checkout are taken away from user
6. After iterating all coupons `CheckoutItems` properties may be presented back to user and create order eventually.

Ps. `Checkout` might not be right name when coupons show its value up front (before adding item to cart), but process shouldn't change imo.

Comment: introducing 'Checkout' object is worth trying. It is a good name, because coupons are applied to cart only. my current implementation is similar, but CartItem has discount property.